# TMS320F28335: Operating two converters using one controller(28335) for battery charger

Tags: battery-charging, embedded, control, microprocessor

I am trying to control two converters using a single DSP 28335.

Converter 1: Three-phase active front end converter(fsw=10kHz) ----sampling frequency= 10kHz(100us)

Converter 2: DC-DC phase shift full bridge converter ( fsw= 50kHz)---- sampling frequnecy= 50 kHz(20 us)

I have implemented ADC in a dual sequence mode where:

SEQ1= Converter 1, SEQ2= Converter 2

When SEQ1 ISR is called:( 100us sampling)

the ADC value of Conv1 is read from the result register only.

When SEQ2 ISR is called:(20us sampling)

1. the ADC value of Conv2 is read from the Result register
2. control loop calculation for Conv1
3. control loop calculation for Conv2

In my opinion, this approach will work fine if SEQ2 ISR operates under less than 20us. On the other hand, writing code for control loop calculation for such time constraint is a challenge in itself.

I am interested to know if there is a better way to approach this problem.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: One thing I can tell you this is possible. I would suggest having only one ISR that runs both control algorithms to save on some overhead and possible jitter. Consider running control loop for DC/DC converter at a lower rate with 50 kHz switching frequency. For any response more detailed than this, please clearly state your questions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have optimized the code using IQmath which reduces the ISR time to 9us which is well within limits.